# SQL - Using a join to pass a list to a lookup tbl

Tags: sql, list, join

I want to  be able to loop over a list and return a single row where all the list elements have matched.

e.g.

lest say my list of id's is 1,2,3 I want to write an SQL statment that will do the following (without breaking).

SELECT id1
FROM TBL
WHERE 0=0
AND id2 = 1
AND id2 = 2
AND id2 = 3

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How can id2 both be 1 _AND_ 2 _AND_ 3 at the same time??? Are you sure that you don't mean or?

Comment: u can remove 0=0 coze its always true

Comment: "loop over a list": A list of what? Where is this list stored? Can you give a worked example to demonstrate what it is that you want?

Comment: The list is a list of id numbers (e.g 1,2,3). I guess what i'm trying to do is query multiple rows in the table so that I only get a results if the table has (in this case) three rows where id1 = 1 and on row 1 id2 =1 and on row 2 id2 =2 and on row 3 id2 = 3

Comment: Does Martin Smith's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want all `id1` records for which there is a matching `id2=1` and a matching `id2=2` and a matching `id2=3`?

```
WITH tbl As
(
SELECT 1 AS id1, 1 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS id1, 2 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS id1, 3 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS id1, 4 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id1, 1 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id1, 2 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS id1, 1 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS id1, 2 AS id2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS id1, 3 AS id2
)
SELECT id1 
FROM tbl 
WHERE id2 IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY id1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id2) = 3
```

Returns

```
id1
-----------
1
3
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Hey guys, THank for your quick response.

Yeah, so there would have to be three rows. Which would look a little like this

ID1 / ID2  
1   / 1  
1   / 2  
1   / 3  
  
Im trying to get the result to eq 1 (the value of id1)

Comment: yeah, thats what i need. I'll try this out and let you know. Thanks for you help

Comment: not only does it work, But I also understand what is going on. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AND here makes no sense. You probably want to use OR: `id2 = 1 OR id2 = 2 OR id2 = 3` or even better IN:

```
SELECT id1 FROM TBL WHERE id2 IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: That would be `SELECT id1 FROM TBL WHERE 0=0 AND id2 = 1 OR id2 = 2 OR id2 = 3`

Comment: @James Curran: The 0=0 is not necessary.

Comment: The point I was making was that he specifically wanted "AND".  You changed it to "OR".

Comment: @James Curran: There is obviously an error in the question. The only question is what the error is. To be honest I think Martin Smith's guess is better than mine, but only the OP knows what he was thinking when he wrote the question.

Comment: Ignore his SQL and read the OP's text.  He clearly wants an "AND" of some form.  (I was thinking of a second table with a many-to-one)

Comment: @James Curran: What do you think the question means? Perhaps you can edit the question to make it clear? I don't really understand what he means by "list" and "looping" in an SQL context and he hasn't replied to my questions. :(

Answer (score 1):

A third guess, based on the title of the question - if the list of values is in a second table, the query can be written to select values from the first table based on a join to the second table - like so:

```
SELECT id1 FROM TBL T1
join TBL2 T2 on T1.id2 = T2.id
```

Of course, in this example TBL2 would have to have only the values 1, 2 and 3 in the id column.